# Difference between :root and body/html

Tags: css

What is the difference between

```
 :root {
    /* some style */
}
```

and

```
html /*(or body)*/ {
/* some style */
}
```

In practice, don't they have the same effect?

Comment: yes they have the same effect but if root is used the all elements that are not targeted get the style

Comment: Also see [:root | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/root/)